# (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /phoenix/live_reload/socket/websocket (ShortenApiWeb.Router)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have been fllowing a code from https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-a-super-fast-link-shortener-with-elixir-phoenix-and-mnesia-70ffa1564b3c to write a url shortener as a means to learn elixir and phoenix .

Whenever I launch my phoenix server on the localhost:4000 it gives this error:

> "Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError at GET /
>   no route found for GET / (ShortenApiWeb.Router)
>   "

Furthermore the terminal says that the way for the live reloading web socket is not also defined:

> [info] GET /phoenix/live_reload/socket/websocket
>   [debug] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /phoenix/live_reload/socket/websocket (ShortenApiWeb.Router)

.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you error because project does not have anything binded to `/` route.

You have to create your links using `curl`

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:4000/api/links/ \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
 "link": {
  "url": "https://twitter.com/bnchrch"
 }
}'
```

And after that you will be able to open it into browser using hash (you should receive it as curl response. Something like `{"data":{"url":"https://twitter.com/bnchrch","hash":"Aode7DEz"}}`

Now you could open `http://localhost:4000/Aode7DEz` and it will redirect you to URL you sent.

Comment: scope "/", ShortenApiWeb do
    get "/:id", LinkController, :get_and_redirect
  end

Comment: it has been defined in the router.ex but there is no redirection

Comment: `get "/:id", LinkController, :get_and_redirect` - means that it binded to `/some`